# hyperv vss writer unexpected error

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012, vss

I am using Mozy Pro to backup our Hyperv servers. I am doing this without any issues on a 2nd server but this box hasn't backed up sucessfully yet.

I was told by the support tech at Mozy to type:

```
vssadmin list providers >c:\providers.txt
vssadmin list writers >c:\writers.txt
```

Writers.txt:

```
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.

Writer name: 'Task Scheduler Writer'
   Writer Id: {d61d61c8-d73a-4eee-8cdd-f6f9786b7124}
   Writer Instance Id: {1bddd48e-5052-49db-9b07-b96f96727e6b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'VSS Metadata Store Writer'
   Writer Id: {75dfb225-e2e4-4d39-9ac9-ffaff65ddf06}
   Writer Instance Id: {088e7a7d-09a8-4cc6-a609-ad90e75ddc93}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Performance Counters Writer'
   Writer Id: {0bada1de-01a9-4625-8278-69e735f39dd2}
   Writer Instance Id: {f0086dda-9efc-47c5-8eb6-a944c3d09381}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'System Writer'
   Writer Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
   Writer Instance Id: {506e7d9c-ded3-4edf-824a-4dd9af7f7538}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'ASR Writer'
   Writer Id: {be000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4}
   Writer Instance Id: {1de438e4-09de-487c-9ea8-eeafbe3fd210}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'COM+ REGDB Writer'
   Writer Id: {542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}
   Writer Instance Id: {511d23d9-4cbb-400f-b739-e6e0a8ecdbee}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer'
   Writer Id: {66841cd4-6ded-4f4b-8f17-fd23f8ddc3de}
   Writer Instance Id: {32f41185-2b20-41ff-a7aa-92c262f578cd}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: Unexpected error

Writer name: 'Registry Writer'
   Writer Id: {afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}
   Writer Instance Id: {fa328ece-623f-43cc-9888-e897e108c40e}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Shadow Copy Optimization Writer'
   Writer Id: {4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f}
   Writer Instance Id: {7b582861-7f7f-4c10-adb1-5106bcab3902}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'WMI Writer'
   Writer Id: {a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0}
   Writer Instance Id: {d2f73a0f-c19a-44cc-bcd2-6c84ac6e516b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'MSMQ Writer (MSMQ)'
   Writer Id: {7e47b561-971a-46e6-96b9-696eeaa53b2a}
   Writer Instance Id: {95ea6efc-c00c-47ca-90d1-28fbe6d7a8d0}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'IIS Config Writer'
   Writer Id: {2a40fd15-dfca-4aa8-a654-1f8c654603f6}
   Writer Instance Id: {d5a32f43-0675-400d-8502-cdece4c867e1}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error
```

Providers.txt:

```
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.

Provider name: 'Microsoft File Share Shadow Copy provider'
   Provider type: Fileshare
   Provider Id: {89300202-3cec-4981-9171-19f59559e0f2}
   Version: 1.0.0.1

Provider name: 'Microsoft Software Shadow Copy provider 1.0'
   Provider type: System
   Provider Id: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
   Version: 1.0.0.7
```

The tech said I needed to resolve this issue:

```
Writer name: 'Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer'
   Writer Id: {66841cd4-6ded-4f4b-8f17-fd23f8ddc3de}
   Writer Instance Id: {32f41185-2b20-41ff-a7aa-92c262f578cd}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: Unexpected error
```

I checked the event viewer and this is the only thing I found related to hyperv:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know where to start to resolve this or to find out where the issue is at. I know nothing of the vss writer for hyperv so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the background disk merge is related to a snapshot being merged with the parent disk. How does the backup software handle snapshots? Is there a snapshot merge occurring during the backup? Does the backup software shutdown the VM during the backup? If so, that would probably explain the merge.

Comment: I have no idea how mozy is doing this. How do I find this out or would you know? Are there any other logs or events that I can review?

Comment: You should talk to Mozy about how their product backs up Hyper-V guests.